# ASP.NET cannot display RadAjaxLoadingPanel for dropdown box because page refreshes

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, telerik, radcombobox

I am working on an asp.net webpage that uses telerik RadComboBoxes and am trying to display a loading spinner using a RadAjaxLoadingPanel when the selected index is change and hide the spinner when some other code completes.

I am having an issue where whenever the index of the combo box changes the page refreshes so my OnSelectedIndexChanged function is called after the page refreshes and the RadAjaxLoadingPanel I try to display doesn't exist yet. Is there a way to run code to show my loading spinner after the combo box index changes but before the page refreshes?

Combo box example

```
<telerik:RadComboBox runat="server" ID="cboReportTypes" OnSelectedIndexChanged="cboReportTypes_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true"></telerik:RadComboBox>
```

loading panel

```
<telerik:RadAjaxLoadingPanel ID="ModalLoadingPanel" runat="server" Transparency="10" BackColor="#E0E0E0" Modal="true">
    <div style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; margin-top: 45px; margin-bottom: auto; width: 135px; height: 80px;"
        class="modalProgress">
        <div class="spinner"></div>
    </div>
</telerik:RadAjaxLoadingPanel>
```

javascript function to show the spinner

```
function showActivityIndicator() {
        console.log("showing the spinner");
        var loadingPanel = $("#<%= ModalLoadingPanel.ClientID %>");
        loadingPanel.show();
    }
```

C# function that is called when drop down index changes (only showing part that displays the spinner)

```
protected void cboReportTypes_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, RadComboBoxSelectedIndexChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "startActivityIndicator", "showActivityIndicator()", true);
    }
```

Displaying the spinner works fine but the page has an error when it is called from the combo box function because the loadingPanel comes back as null because the page refreshed.

Any help is appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: Did you check sample in this page http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/combobox/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx? Do you have a   `<telerik:RadScriptManager runat="server" ID="RadScriptManager1" />` on your page

Answer (score 0):

So after a lot of searching I ended up finding the solution in one of the many tabs I had open in my browser.

I found that there is another callback function available for a RadComboBox called OnClientSelectedIndexChanging which runs before the page refreshes. So by calling my javascript function directly from that callback function I am able to get my spinner to display after the index changes while the user waits for the page to refresh with the changed data.

```
<telerik:RadComboBox runat="server" ID="cboReportTypes" OnClientSelectedIndexChanging="showActivityIndicator" OnSelectedIndexChanged="cboReportTypes_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true"></telerik:RadComboBox>
```